# PHP: form redirection after validating its fields

Tags: php, forms

I have done a simple form like this:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<?php
  $name = "";
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
      // handle missing field
    } else {
      $name = $_POST["name"];
    }
  }
  if($name != '') {
    header('location: http://localhost/new_page.php');
    exit();
  }
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
      <span class="label">Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <button><span>Validate</span></button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like the following behaviour:

- staying on the form if the name field is not set by the user
- going to new_page.php if name field is set

I have the following error right now: if I set the name, I am redirected to a blank.php page.
Can someone help me on this ? Or at least give me some tips to debug this as I am not really a PHP specialist.

Thank you !

Comment: either give input field required validation or need to use ajax

Comment: Ok, so I can simply use "required" in input fields and the above is correct ?

Comment: Yes you can use.

Comment: on server side also redirect on same page if not getting value in any case, dont rely all time on required

Comment: I tried using required. But if all fields are set, I am still redirected to a blank page and I do not know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header call comes too late.

an HTTP Response first has a header, then a body. HTML code is the body.

You need to put all output AFTER your PHP code. Since you start with `<html>`, headers will already have been sent and so your redirect will not work.

Also, regarding white pages (White screen of death or WSOD):

For the best error logging experience, set error_reporting to -1, turn display_errors off, and set a custom error_log. Then in the terminal, type 'tail -f /path/to/error_log'. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you!

Comment: you're very welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @delboy1978uk is correct.
All you have to do is change your file content to:

```
<?php
  $name = "";
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
      // handle missing field
    } else {
      $name = $_POST["name"];
    }
    if($name != '') {
      header('location: http://localhost/new_page.php');
      exit();
    }
  }

?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
      <span class="label">Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <button><span>Validate</span></button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```